# Block values that are smaller than the previous iteration

Tags: arrays, c, loops

This loop checks the previous element in an array. The question is how can it be avoided to check the `arr[0][0]` with its previous element which causes undefined behavior?

Here is the code so far but it has this issue with the the first element being checked with its previous element.

```
int main()
{
    int arr[2][4];
    int k, n;

    for (k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
        for (n = 0; n < 4; n++) {

            do {
                printf("Provide a number");
                scanf("%d", &arr[k][n]);
                printf("This is %d in the position[%d][%d]\n", arr[k][n], k, n);
                if (n==0) break;
                printf("The arr[k][n] is %d and the arr[k][n-1] is %d and n-1 means %d\n", arr[k][n], arr[k][n - 1], n - 1);
            } while (arr[k][n] <= arr[k][n - 1]); //Here is the issue
        }
    }
    for (k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
        for (n = 0; n < 4; n++) {
            printf("%d\n", arr[k][n]);
        }
    }
}
```

The issue:

Adding the `if (n==0) break;` causes the program to allow adding smaller numbers than the ones inserted so far. While not including this line causes undefined behavior. How can this be fixed?

This is how it works now, which is not correct:

```
2       3       4       5
2       4       5       6
```

The `printf` statements are only for the purpose of viewing what is going on.

Comment: What is your condition to allow numbers? You do not check with numbers of previous line `arr[k-1]` at all. What's wrong with the shown numbers?

Comment: Each number that is added should be larger than all the rest (previous numbers that have been added already), no matter the row/column.

Comment: Then why do you care about cols/rows? Just store `last_number` and compare with `new_number` before storing in the array. The condition for `break` would then be `if (n==0 && k == 0)`

Comment: For future question I suggest a few improvements: Title and body should match. If you get wrong output, tell us (in the question body, not in comments) what output is expected and why. Also your body is inconsistent: The `break` you have, perfectly avoids checking previous elements that would cause UB. Your problem was a different one (that from the title).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only check with previous column. That is not related to your `break` but due to broken logic.

You could do it like this:

```c
int main()
{
    int arr[2][4];
    int k, n;
    int last_number, new_number;

    for (k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
        for (n = 0; n < 4; n++) {

            do {
                printf("Provide a number");
                scanf("%d", &new_number);
                printf("This is %d in the position[%d][%d]\n", new_number, k, n);
                if (n==0 && k == 0)
                    break;  // Don't check for increasing values.
            } while (new_number < last_number);

            arr[k][n] = new_number;
            last_number = new_number;
        }
    }

    for (k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
        for (n = 0; n < 4; n++) {
            printf("%d\n", arr[k][n]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the `(n==0 && k == 0)` part, what exactly does it do?

Comment: That avoids doing an extra iteration for the very first value. `arr[0][0]` must be accepted without any checks.

Comment: even simply adding `if (n==0 && k == 0)` in my code seems to solve the issue without issues. You added the `new number` and `last number` variables  to make it better overall. Am I right?

Comment: I added `last_number` to keep the largest value from first row. That is due to your comment *be larger than all the rest (previous numbers that have been added already), no matter the row/column.*

Comment: last_number is uninitialized

Comment: @stark on the very first run of the inner `for` loop, we will skip the condition of `while` as `n==0 && k == 0`. Directly afterwards it will be assigned a value that can be used in next iteration.

Comment: @Gerhardh I tested it and only adding `if (n==0 && k == 0)` does the trick, even checks the previous rows.

Comment: @user18528430 with your old code? That's wrong. For `n==0 && k==1` your code still accesses `arr[k][n-1]` which is wrong. Also your code does not prevent entering the numbers you show as invalid input. You should start using a debugger and step through your code. Watch each instruction and check the values of your variables. If that was a valid solution, I would not have done more changes.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
while (arr[k][n] <= arr[k][n - 1]);
```

to

```
while (n > 0 && arr[k][n] <= arr[k][n - 1]);
```

This works because && short circuits the test when n == 0 and does not do the second test.

You will also need to fix the print statement.

Comment: This has the same flaw that a larger value in previous line is not detected.

Comment: I do believe, the title and the whole description should be taken into account.

Comment: valid point. logic is incorrect.

Comment: The purpose of the loop is to be infinite until a valid number is entered.